# Как использовать Python3.x вместо Python2.x в Eclipse на Debian

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, eclipse, python-2.x

При попытке компиляции проекта в Eclipse на Debian, компилятор не распознает черное на белом

Например, в строке

```
print(a[i], end='')
```

Выдает ошибку

```
print(a[i], end='')
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Видимо, он продолжает использовать Python второй версии вместо третьей.

Обновлял змейку по разным советам. Например, по [совету](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-debian-9/)

НО! Компилятор упрямо продолжает использовать Python 2.7

Будьте добры, как мне выйти из ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалось, дело в том, что нужный интерпретатор просто не был выбран должным образом.

И так, после установки нужной версии Python3.x, например [Python3.7](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-debian-9/) необходимо выполнить следующие действия:

1. Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter
2. Выбрать Python-2.x и удалить из списка
3. Нажать на Choose from list
4. Выбрать нужную версию Python-3.x